# C pointer casting to and from Go

Tags: c, go, ffmpeg, cgo

I'm writing an app for the windows platform using FFmpeg and it's golang wrapper goav, but I'm having trouble understanding how to pass the C pointers between C and Go.

I've stripped out all the relevant parts of the C code, the wrapper and my code, shown below:

C code - libavutil/frame.h

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct AVFrame {
#define AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS 8
    uint8_t *data[AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS];
}
```

Go `goav` wrapper

```
package avutil

/*
    #cgo pkg-config: libavutil
    #include <libavutil/frame.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    // C code I added:
    #include <stdio.h>

    void SaveFrame(const char* location, uint8_t *data, int width, int height) {
        FILE *pFile;
        int  y;

        // Open file
        pFile=fopen(location, "wb");
        if(pFile==NULL)
            return;

        // Write header
        fprintf(pFile, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", width, height);

        // Write pixel data
        for(y=0; y<height; y++)
            fwrite(data+y*width, 1, width*3, pFile);

        // Close file
        fclose(pFile);
    }
*/
import "C"
import (
    "unsafe"
)

type Frame C.struct_AVFrame

func Data(f *Frame) *uint8 {
    // i think this is the function thats not working?
    return (*uint8)(unsafe.Pointer((*C.uint8_t)(unsafe.Pointer(&f.data))))
}
func SaveFrame(location string, data *uint8, width int, height int) {
    C.SaveFrame(C.CString(location), unsafe.Pointer(data), C.int(width), C.int(height))
}
```

My Go code

```
package main

import "github.com/giorgisio/goav/avutil"

func main() {
    var frame *avutil.Frame
    var data *uint8

    //... initialize frame

    data = avutil.Data(frame)
    avutil.SaveFrame("frame0.ppm", data, 1920, 1080)
}
```

When I try to save the frame, the resulting image is garbled because the pointer is wrong, how do i fix this?

Comment: `data` in `struct AVFrame` is not a pointer but an array of pointer. `return (*uint8)(unsafe.Pointer((*C.uint8_t)(unsafe.Pointer(&f.data))))` is totally wrong but I don't know much of go, so I can't help you more.

Comment: FYI the lagugage is called Go; "golang" is a keyword interpreted by a popular Internet search engine to find material related to that language. (Otherwise please also use "Clang", "Javalang", "Erlanglang" and so on.) ;-)

Comment: Note that you need to free C.CString(location) otherwise it is a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

The `data` field of the `AVFrame` struct is an array of 8 pointers.

That is, it's a contiguous chunk of memory containing 8 slots
adjacent to each other—each holding a pointer (to a value of type `uint8_t`).

IOW, the declaration

```
uint8_t *data[AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS];
```

is better interpreted as

```
uint8_t* data[AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS];
```

and in Go, you'd declare it something like

```
var data [AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS]*uint8_t
```

Now your `SaveFrame` function declares its `data` arguments to
be of type `uint8_t*`. That is okay to pass the address of the
`data` array of an `AVFrame` struct as that argument, but more idiomatic
would be to pass the address of its zeroth element—something like

```
func Data(frame *Frame) *uint8 {
    return (*uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(&frame.data[0]))
}
```

Comment: It should be `return *uint8(`

Comment: Is there any reason the pointer would become invalid? I'm passing it to glTexImage2D but getting a horrible error: `Exception 0xc0000005 0x0 0x3d21f000 0x77572510      PC=0x77572510`

Comment: I had a similar error trying to save the data with Go and had to write a C function (that I pass the Frame context to) which used `fwrite(frame->data[0]+y*frame->linesize[0], ...` and that worked, but I just can't seem to get the right data in Go